# using optimr to minimize a function

Tags: r

I am trying to run the optimr  function from the optimr package.  My code is

```
library(optimr)

#____function to compute Sum of Square Errors 
SSE=function(par,T) {
    options(warn = -1)

    nr = dim(T)[1]   # number of redds (rows)
    S  = numeric(nr) # redd survival vector
    TC = par[1]    
    bt = par[2] 

    #--- temperature deviations dT=(Ti-TC)
    dT = sweep(T,1,TC,FUN='-') 
    dT = ifelse(is.na(dT)|dT<0,0,dT)

    h = bt*dT 

    for(i in 1:nr) S[i] = 1-prod(exp(-h[i,]))


    SSE = sum((S-mean(S))^2)  # same as var(S)*(nr-1)

   options(warn = 0)
}

#___ Data
Temp = matrix(round(rnorm(2000,12,1.5),2), ncol=20)  #fictious data used   
hist(Temp,col='grey60')

#____ minimize SSE via optimizer
o = optimr(par=c(8,.01),fn=SSE,T=Temp,method='Nelder-Mead') 
print(cbind(Tcrit=o$par[1],bt=o$par[2]),digits=3)
```

The problem is that no matter what initial parameter values I give the command, it returns the same initial values.  I know that if the starting values were on a flat surface, those values would not change, but no matter what values I give it, the sames ones get returned.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Eventually the `options(warn = 0)` causes it. It defines the return value of your function `SSE`

Comment: thank you so much.  I was trying to avoid excessive info on the screen and it appears that is preventing my parameter estimates to change.